# how to make specific properties of object as array of object in javascript and add it to same object

Tags: javascript

I need to transform the below array of objects into a modified array of object

```
obj = [{
    org_id: 'CLTINTGBK0001',  
    rate: 8,
    qty: 500,
    total_rate: 35000
  },
  {
    org_id: 'CLTINTGBK0001',  
    rate: 7,
    qty: 800,
    total_rate: 38000
  }
]
```

Goal:

```
  obj =  [  {
        org_id: 'CLTINTGBK0001',  
       "qty": [
            { 
                "qty": 500,
                "rate":8
            }
        ],
        total_rate: 38000
      },
      {
        org_id: 'CLTINTGBK0001',  
       "qty": [
            { 
                "qty": 800,
                "rate":7
            }
        ],
        total_rate: 38000
      }
    ]
```

I have the below code however it's not working. I am trying to loop the array of obect and created different array and object and push object to array and add the array to each object of array.

```
let obj1 = {}
let qrty
let qty = []
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    qrt1 = arr[i].qty
    rate1 = arr[i].rate
    console.log(qrty)
    obj1.qty = qrt1;
    obj1.rate = rate1;

    qty.push(obj1);
    arr[i].qty = qty
    console.log('arr', arr)
}
```

Comment: Wait. Both `total_rate` should be 38000? Or the first one should be 35000?

Comment: sorry first one should 35000

Comment: If there's only going to be one object in the `qty` array why have the array at all. Why not just `qty: { amount: 5, rate: 3 }`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Destructuring Assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const obj = [
  { org_id: 'CLTINTGBK0001', rate: 8, qty: 500, total_rate: 35000 },
  { org_id: 'CLTINTGBK0001', rate: 7, qty: 800, total_rate: 38000 },
];

let res = obj.map(({ qty, rate, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  qty: [{ qty, rate }],
}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```js
const obj = [{
org_id: 'CLTINTGBK0001',  
rate: 8,
qty: 500,
total_rate: 35000
  },
  {
org_id: 'CLTINTGBK0001',  
rate: 7,
qty: 800,
total_rate: 38000
  }
]

var newObject = []

obj.forEach(element => {

var newElem = {}
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(element)){
    if(key == 'qty'){
        newElem[key]= {
            qty: element['qty'],
            rate: element['rate'],
        }
    }else if (key == 'rate'){
        continue
    }else{
        newElem[key] = value
    }
}

newObject.push(newElem)
});

console.log(newObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
let  obj = [
  { org_id: 'CLTINTGBK0001', rate: 8, qty: 500, total_rate: 35000 },
  { org_id: 'CLTINTGBK0001', rate: 7, qty: 800, total_rate: 38000 }
];

obj = obj.map((item)=> {
  return {
    org_id: item.org_id,
    total_rate: item.total_rate,
    qty:[   {   qty: item.qty, rate:item.rate } ]
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```